# why is my navigationBar under my status bar?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

http://www.irovr.com/stackOverflow/overlap.png

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
        [mainScrollView addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onMainScrollTap:)]];
    }

- (void)onMainScrollTap:(id)sender {
    if(self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden){
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
        [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
    }else{
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
        [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
    }
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
    self.navigationController.toolbar.translucent = YES;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    self.navigationController.toolbar.translucent = NO;
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that hiding the status bar and navigation bar at the same time causes this problem.  I was able to resolve it by hiding/showing the navigation bar with `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay`, even with a delay of 0

Comment: This worked for me as well.  I was able to get it to "re-frame" by setting `navigationBarHidden` to YES and then NO immediately.

Answer (score 5):

Using "performSelector" will work.

However, some may find it easier to add the following to "viewWillDisappear" even if there is already a statement that unhides the navigation bar.

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view is set too large, so it's getting drawn underneath the status bar. If you're using Interface Builder to create it as a .xib, you need to enabled the setting for the status bar under "Simulated Interface Elements", or just reduce the height of your view manually.

Comment: That isn't it. My view is sized appropriately. Perhaps I should have mentioned that this only happens when I have hidden the status and navigation bars and show them again. The view is meant to toggle between full screen and not, just like the photos app.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)fixNavigationBarUnderStatusbarBug
{
    //This method fix bug! Don't cut it
    //Bug: Statusbar hide navigationBar after device rotation.
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        NSOperationQueue *mainQueue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
        [center addObserverForName:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil
                             queue:mainQueue usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                 UIApplication *currentApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
                                 if (currentApplication.statusBarHidden) {
                                     [currentApplication setStatusBarHidden:NO];
                                     double delayInSeconds = .1;
                                     dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
                                     dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                                         [currentApplication setStatusBarHidden:YES];
                                     });
                                 }
                             }];
    }
}
```